# Change first week of the year in fullcalendar.io

Tags: fullcalendar, ui-calendar

I would like to change the First week of the year. fullcalendar.io

Current View

[image]

Shift the Start of week down

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/apq34.png]

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there is no builtin functionality for this. You could use such trick:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
  },
  defaultView: 'month',
  weekNumbers: true,
  viewRender: function(view, element) {
      $('.fc-week-number').each(function(i, obj) {
      var weekNumber = $(obj).find('span:first').text();
      if ($.isNumeric(weekNumber)) {
        if (parseInt(weekNumber) == 1) {
          $(obj).find('span:first').text('');
        } else {
          $(obj).find('span:first').text(parseInt(weekNumber) - 1);
        }
      }

    });
  }
});
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fe4vt3tp/).

Comment: Actually, what i want do is, I want to keep a custom start week of the year. For example i want to start the week from March 3rd week or anywhere in the calendar.